# I get blank report after publish. Using Crystal Reports 13 ( Visual Studio 2012 IIS 7)

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

My reports are working perfectly on local machine. I mean when run from vs.net. The reports are not working even i deploy it to the same system. I tried different solutions but with no luck. I have checked multiple stack-overflow questions and their solutions but still i am stuck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just after posting my question here at stack-overflow i found a blog which solve my problem. So this may help other people having trouble to view crystal report after publishing. As I wasted two days searching for a fix to this issue. At last I found the solution on the following [Site Link](http://www.smarterasp.net/support/KB/a357/why-do-i-get-blank-page-after-publish-crystal-reports.aspx)

All the credit goes to the Original Author who made that blog. I just copy/past his/her steps

**Solution**

**This issue does not occur in local but happens when you host the site on server in IIS. Actually the cause of the issue is that Crystal Report is unable to find the required JavaScript (JS) files to render the report in browser**

Below are the steps to resolve the issue

1. Downloading and installing runtime for Crystal Reports 13 for Visual Studio 2010. (You might want to skip this step if you already did this before and your application is working locally).
2. Once the runtime is installed. Crystal Reports will install the required support files in the location of your local computer:
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13
3. Copy the entire Crystal Report Support folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13  to your Website's  SITE_ROOT\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 folder.

4) If you do not have a   \aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 folders in your website's root. Please create them manually and then copy the crystalreportviewers13 into it.

**NOTE: You can just copy the entire aspnet_client folder and past it to the site's root. It will work**

Comment: I have tried the same way, still my design is not as in local development. :(

Comment: Point 3 was the final thing that fixed this for me. As well as installing the runtime, copy the aspnet_client folder into the root of my site.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The solution is to work on IIS  this way:

- **Copy `aspnet_client` folder** from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the **new website root folder**.

***or*** (first one is easier, second one is better fro maintenance)

- **Create a virtual directory** called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client` **inside the new website**

### Problem analysis

It's possible to analyze the problem

- using **client tools** (debug window of browser)

`GET    http://someserver:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js 403 (Forbidden)`
`GET
 http://someserver:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css 403 (Forbidden)`

- or **server tool** (IIS log , on WIN2003 is placed in `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC###\` on WIN2008 `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC###`).

> 2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!
>   2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!

### Cause the problem

**Crystal Reports runtime is installed, but your application is not running under default web site.**

- In both cases i found that `crv.js` and `style.css` some files were not served;
- these files are placed by CR installer in `wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder, but for some reasons they cannot be reached;
- In my case the reason is that i create a **different website (port 20080) and aspnet_client folder is not placed inside that website**

I can see that you use different versions of software and different configurations, but **i think you have the same problem**.

Answer (score -1):

I just copied the app_client folder to the published code folder's root then it started working fine.